# trouble understanding composition of measurable function with poisson process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E_1 \subseteq \mathbb R^{d_1},E_2 \subseteq \mathbb R^{d_2}$ with sigma algebras $\mathcal E_1,\mathcal E_2$. Let $T:E_1 \to E_2$ be measurable with respect to these two. Then let $N$ be a poisson random measure (poisson process) with mean $\mu$.

Show that $\widetilde{N} = N \circ T$ is a poisson random measure with mean $\widetilde{\mu} = \mu \circ T^{-1}$

I am having trouble interpreting what $\widetilde{N}$ actually means, it is the distribution of $T$ under the poisson process, $N$? and what does that even mean, and then I'm approaching by trying to solve:
$$
P(\widetilde{N}(A) =k)
$$
and showing that this is poisson distributed, but I'm not sure how to intrepret:
$$
P(N \circ T =k)
$$

**update** From these [set of notes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCIQFjABahUKEwiaxpDTy4rIAhVBKx4KHTEwBL0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9780387878584-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1092139-p173847309&usg=AFQjCNErNZ4yexXefYwatYqUUBYmMsAwww&sig2=AGg1n3zVuif5wRLp4k1I6w&cad=rja), I think the question I had was written incorrectly, it should be that $\widetilde{N} = N \circ T^{-1}$ and we may write:
$$
\widetilde{N}(\omega,B) = N(\omega,T^{-1}B) 
$$
for $\omega \in \Omega$ and $B \in \mathcal E_2$.

So what is $N(\omega,T^{-1}B)$?, I think I can proceed as follows:
$$
P(\widetilde{N}(B)=k) = P(N(T^{-1}B)=k) = e^{-\mu(T^{-1}B)}\frac{(\mu(T^{-1}B))^k}{k!}
$$
Im still confused by the notation, Can I say that $\mu(T^{-1}B)) = \mu \circ T^{-1}(B)$ and so the result is obvious?

Comment: I'm guessing that $N\circ T$ is the measure 
$$N\circ T(E) := N(T(E))$$
I am unsure about the mean.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I've updated my attempt, maybe the question makes a bit more sense now..not too sure though

Comment: The definition of Poisson process measure that I remember differs from yours, but that looks correct.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Why does the last statement hold? could you by any chance explain that notation ?

Comment: $\mu\circ T^{-1}(B) := \mu (T^{-1}(B)$ is really a measure, called the push forward measure of $T$. So as $B$ varies, the equation above is really an equation of set-functions. I am assuming that you know that $P(N(B) = k) = e^{\mu(B)} \frac{\mu(B)^k}{k!}$ implies that it is a Poisson process with mean $\mu$ (because I personally haven't seen it that way) but with this, we can then conclude that the mean is $\mu\circ T^{-1}$.

Comment: Also @dimebucker91 It seems that your link is to a file stored locally on your computer... :)

Comment: @CalvinKhor woops, fixed now, didn't realise it had saved on to my computer before linking it

Comment: @CalvinKhor This along with independence would prove that its a PRM, how would you go about proving it otherwise?

Comment: I am not familiar with treating a stochastic process purely by its induced measure on path space. I believe, given your definition, that is the right way to do it.